# How to dynamically extend ES5 and ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to build a tool library to be used on every environment. I have a transpiler so my generated code is ES5.

The thing is my tool hooks on a class methods and injects them back in the prototype:

```
klass.prototype = Object.create(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(klass.prototype),
  modifiedDescriptors
);
```

But if a ES6 class is passed we can't modify it's `prototype` because it's descriptor is `{configurable: false, writable: false}`. So I decided to fully extend the class with ES5 code and not modify the original prototype:

```
function ProxyCtor() { return klass.apply(this, arguments) }
ProxyCtor.prototype = Object.create(klass.prototype, modifiedDescriptors);
```

Again this is not possible because a ES6 class constructor can't be invoked without `new`: `Class constructor X cannot be invoked without 'new'`

Ok no problem I'll drop ES5 support and my code will extend the class using ES6 classes and then I will finally be able to hook the methods:

```
class ProxyCtor extends klass {}

Object.defineProperty(ProxyCtor, 'prototype', Object.create(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(ProxyCtor.prototype),
  modifiedDescriptors
);
```

And this again fails because `ProxyCtor.prototype` is readonly as `klass.prototype` was.

I could use `Proxy` for this but a requirement is to support older browsers and for optimization reasons I need the calculations to be executed on script startup and not when the method is called.

So the question is... how can I extend a class ES6 (meaning it should have the same behaviour and `new ProxyCtor() instanceof klass` should be true) but wrap it's methods with a function?

Comment: You'll want to have a look at the decorators proposal.

Comment: The idea is to use this as a decorator but it should be usable in project which doesn't transpile. In fact this code should be executed even when used as a decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of `Object.create` to overwrite the `.prototype` with a new object could as easily be

```
Object.defineProperties(klass.prototype, modifiedDescriptors)
```

that keeps the object the same but changes its properties.

Comment: Indeed, I was trying to keep immutability but we're already mutating the class so... Thank you so much for your answer @bergi